# In the Wagtail admin how to disable summary items of Images and Documents?

Tags: django, python-3.x, wagtail

I know that I can get rid of the Pages summary by using the hook, in fact a code sample below should have removed all the items, however Images and Documents still remain.

```
@hooks.register("construct_homepage_summary_items")
def hide_images_and_documents_from_partners(request, summary_items):
    if request.user.groups.filter(name="Partners").exists():
        summary_items.clear()
```

[image: summary of images documents]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wagtail` too internally uses the `construct_homepage_summary_items` hook, therefore to make this work correctly one must pass `order` argument to the `hooks.register()` to make this hook run after every hook in the wagtail core.

To hide Images and Documents summary items one could use the following code:

```
from wagtail.admin.site_summary import PagesSummaryItem

@hooks.register("construct_homepage_summary_items", order=1)
def hide_everything_except_pages_summary_for_partners(request, summary_items):
    if request.user.groups.filter(name="Partners").exists():
        summary_items[:] = [i for i in summary_items if isinstance(i, PagesSummaryItem)]
```